# How to get value by column name in csv using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I would like to get value by column name (not index) in rails

```
stopid,stopname,location
1,test1,loc1
2,test2,loc2

CSV.foreach( input_stops, encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8' ) do |row|
  p row['stopid']
end
```

But it doesn't work.
Is there any solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to include `headers: true` for that:

```
CSV.foreach(input_stops,
            encoding: 'iso-8859-1:utf-8',
            headers: true) do |row|
  p row['stopid']
end

# Prints:
"1"
"2"
 => nil
```

Or if you want to use headers as symbols:

```
CSV.foreach(input_stops,
            encoding: 'iso-8859-1:utf-8',
            headers: true,
            header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
  p row[:stopid]
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it work, but I have one more problem, 
The first column contains ï»¿, so row['stopid'] don't work.
row is "{"ï»¿ stopid"=>0, ... }

Comment: That is not mentioned anywhere in your question. Acc to that, your first column is 'stopid'.